# Is there a difference between "click" function vs e.target in javascript? Performance speed?

Tags: javascript

Is there any major difference in using

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    //kk
})
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    //kk
})
```

VS

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    if(e.target.closest(#button){
        //kk
    }else if(e.target.closest(#button2){
        //kk
    }
})
```

Is there a performance benefit for looping though `if` statements or just attaching individual listener for each element that is clickable?

Comment: The first one. Talking in Big O notation both are `O(1)`. That aside, what's easier to maintain is the best you can do. The important thing is knowing the linear time the Browser takes to bubble that event throughout all the layers until it reached that button. In such case, the second one (with `if / else`) it's not the best thing you could do because of the many *check* steps. Also, instead of `document` would be wiser to use a closest known common parent as delegator.

Comment: `Also, instead of document would be wiser to use a closest known common parent as delegator.` So something like `document.getElementById("parent_parent").querySelector('#button).addEventListener`?

Comment: No, If you already know a button ID, there's no gain in going for a parent beforehand. That was related to the second example you used.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("click",function(e){` would be best as i.e: `EL_menu.addEventListener("click", function(e){` - well... unless your dynamic elements will be scattered all around the website in unknown places. If you already stored somewhere a menu element like `EL_menu` it's later always quicker to start querying child element from it than rewinding up all down from `document` and search again the entire DOM tree.

Answer (score 3):

### Dynamic elements

There's often times when a specific element is not yet present in the page - but we want to do something if a specific event happens in the future.
In such circumstances a common way to tackle the problem is to use an ancestor delegator (like `document` or a closest known Element).

```js
// We don't have buttons yet, but might appear in the future
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {

  const EL_btn = evt.target.closest("button");

  if (!EL_btn) return; // No button was clicked. Play dead!

  if (EL_btn.id === "foo") {
    console.log("Button #foo was clicked!")
  }

});
```

If those elements could be *anywhere* in such case we use `document` and call it a day. But if we know exactly the parent container that will hold those child elements **always use that element** as delegator. I.e: `EL_asideMenu.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {` to prevent querying back again the entire DOM tree.

### Dynamic elements pt2:

When creating *in-memory* elements, assign at creation a click handler. Append your elements (when time comes) where needed - and that's it. No need to do DOM events querying or other stuff.

```js
const NewEL = (tag, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), attr); 

const navButtons = [
  {type: "button", textContent: "Say Hi!", onclick() { console.log("Hello World!"); }},
  {type: "button", textContent: "Say Foo", onclick() { console.log("Foo!Bar!Baz!"); }},
].map(attr => NewEL("button", attr));

document.querySelector("#navee").append(...navButtons);
```

```html
<nav id="navee"></nav>
```

***Pro tip:*** in the above example, that's the only, proper and sole time you want to use the `on*` attribute handlers on an Element. Since the element is just being created. Every other time you should use `Element.addEventListener()` to **attach** additional handlers. But never again the `on*` to not override any prior handler.

### Static elements

That's when direct Events assignment is preferrable

```js
const myButtonHandler = (ev) => {
  const EL_btn = ev.currentTarget;  // Use currentTarget in that case!
  if (EL_btn.id === "foo") {
    console.log("Button #foo was clicked!")
  }
};

// Buttons exist already and are never going to change
// So let's go grab'em
const ELs_btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");

// Assign a "click" Event handler 
ELs_btns.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", myButtonHandler));
```

Now, regarding both the above examples and their `if` and possible **lots of  `else` statements**, you could create a "map" with functions for every button - by storing the desired function name inside a `data-*` attribute:

```js
const clickFn = (ev) => ({
  sayHi()     { console.log("Hello, World!") }, 
  myOtherFn() { console.log("Something else!") },
}[ev.currentTarget.dataset.click](ev)); 

const ELs_btns = document.querySelectorAll("[data-click]");
ELs_btns.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", clickFn));
```

```html
<button data-click="sayHi" type="button">Say hello!</button>
<button data-click="myOtherFn" type="button">Do something else</button>
```

or many other ways... like a `switch .. case`, `if .. else` etc...